# Laravel Store GMT Based on Location

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

$now = new DateTime();

This Statement store GMT+0:00.
I want to store the GMT +5:30.
How can i do it ..any ideas and suggestions welcome.

Comment: You can set the timezone in the config. As shown in this example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#accessing-configuration-values.

Comment: Thanks it is easy and so we dont have to give timezone in each DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your desired timezone in constructor as mentioned in the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Example.

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
```